# How can I use "metrics.mutual_info" in scikit's feature.selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis

I would like to use other scoring functions then `chi2` etc., that are not listed on this page.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html

For example `metrics.mutual_info` and `metrics.balanced_accuracy_score`

How can I integrate those into my code?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new scikit-learn version 0.18, has added support for Mutual information feature selection. So no need to use the `metrics.mutual_info`. You can use the new [feature_selection.mutual_info_classif](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html) score function in `SelectKBest` or `SelectPercentile` just like you use `chi2`.

```
X_new = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k=100).fit_transform(X, y)
```

For more information about the resent changes look at the [changelog](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html).